# jquery to loop through table for text comparison

Tags: jquery, text, comparison

Looping through the table is not a problem.

Looping through the table and do comparison at the same time assigning the other td in same row with different value is a problem. How can this be done ???

```
- going through #tblView tbody tr.class

        - to find through all row for second td and see whether the .text() is "completed"
                - if yes
                        - then third td's span's inner text set to "bingo"
                - else
                        - do nothing
                - end


<table id="tblView">

<tbody>

<tr class="class">

<td>completed</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

</tr>

<tr class="class">

<td>not yet</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: can you post your html structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try -

```
$("#tblView tbody tr.class").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text() === "completed") $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text('bingo'); 
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d45ZQ/1/